# Pass data from a JavaScript array to an HTML form

Tags: javascript, html, json

I am trying to learn JavaScript and I came across a practice problem in a book I purchased that I cannot seem to crack. The task is to flesh out a javascript formBuilder function to generate HTML forms dynamically from a JavaScript array. I have copied the code from the book onto a CodePen page for visual and testing purposes.

CodePen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gpwZMX

HTML sample:

```
<div>
  <button data-sample='1'>Run 1</button>
  <button data-sample='2'>Run 2</button>
  <button data-sample='3'>Run 3</button>
</div>

<hr>
<div id='spec'>
  <i>This div will display the currently-processed spec</i>
</div>
<br>Output:
<div id='result'>
  <i>I sure wish I had a cool html form in me...</i>
</div>

<!--here are some test cases in docblock form-->
<div class='testcase' id='1'>
  /** Comment Form
     * Make a comment on the blog post!
     * @param  string[100] title
     * @param  email email
     * @param  text body
     * @param  bool subscribe Email me when someone comments on my comment!
     */
</div>
```

JavaScript sample:

```
var samples = [
  {
    title:"Comment Form",
    desc:"Make a comment on the blog post!",
    params:[
      { 
        type: 'text',
        max_length: 100,
        name: 'title'
      },
      {
        type: 'email',
        name: 'email'
      },
      {
        type:'textarea',
        name:'body'
      },
      {
        type:'checkbox',
        name:'subscribe',
        label:'mail me when someone comments on my comment!'
      }
    ]
  }]
```

formBuilder sample:

```
//builds an HTML form using all information present in `spec` and places the resulting HTML in jquery element `$el`
function formBuilder(spec,$el){
  $el.html("<i>I still wish I had a cool html form in me...</i>");
}


$("button").on("click",function($e){
  var specIndex = $($e.target).data('sample');
  var specData = samples[specIndex-1];

  $("#spec").html("Sample spec "+(specIndex)+" looks like: <br>"+JSON.stringify(specData));

  formBuilder(specData, $("#result"));
});
```

Comment: that's not json. that's just javascript...

Comment: Try looking here http://api.jquery.com/append/.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: I'm trying to create an HTML form that uses data from a JavaScript array but I cannot figure out the best way to do so. Do I use the append method $( ".result ).append( "?" ); in my HTML code or in the formBuilder portion of the JavaScript...or neither? I am new to JavaScript so please view the CodePen link for a better understanding of the problem. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gpwZMX @ctwheels

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Errors in the codepen code exist, paste the code below into your project:

```
var samples = [
{
    title:"Comment Form",
    desc:"Make a comment on the blog post!",
    params:[
      { 
        type: 'text',
        max_length: 100,
        name: 'title'
      },
      {
        type: 'email',
        name: 'email'
      },
      {
        type:'textarea',
        name:'body'
      },
      {
        type:'checkbox',
        name:'subscribe',
        label:'mail me when someone comments on my comment!'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    title:"Car Order Form",
    desc:"Choose your car!",
    params:[
      { 
        type:'select',
        values:['red','blue','green','black','white','taupe'],
        name: 'color'
      },
      {
        type: 'checkbox',
        values:['fog-lights','radio','a-c','wheels','headlights'],
        name: 'options'
      },
      {
        type:'string',
        minLength:7,
        maxLength:7,
        name:'vanityPlate',
        optional:true
      },
      {
        type:'int',
        name:'price',
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    title:"New User Creator",
    desc:"Create a new user account",
    params:[
      { 
        type:'string',
        maxLength:20,
        name:'fname',
        label:'First Name'
      },
      { 
        type:'string',
        maxLength:20,
        name:'lname',
        label:'Last Name'
      },
      { 
        type:'date',
        name:'dob',
        label:'Date of Birth'
      },
      {
        type:'email',
        multiple:true,
        maxCount:4,
        name:'emails',
        label:'Email Addresses'
      },
      {
        type: 'string',
        name: 'addr1',
        label: 'Street Address'
      },
      {
        type: 'string',
        name: 'city'
      },
      {
        type: 'state',
        name: 'state',
      },
      {
        type: 'int',
        name: 'zipcode',
        maxValue: 99999,
        minValue: 0,
        label: 'ZIP'
      },
    ]
  }
]

//builds an HTML form using all information present in `spec` and places the resulting HTML in jquery element `$el`
function formBuilder(spec,$el){
  var inputs = getInputs(spec);
  $el.html("<form title='"+spec.title+"'><fieldset><legend>"+spec.desc+"</legend>"+inputs+"</fieldset></form>");
}

function getInputs(spec) {
  var inputs = "";
  for(var i = 0; i < spec.params.length; i++) {
    var input = "<input ";
    var attributes = JSON.stringify(spec.params[i]).split(",");
    console.log(attributes);
    for(var j = 0; j < attributes.length; j++) {
      $.each(spec.params[i], function(key, value) {
        input += key + "='" + value + "' ";
      });
    }
    inputs += input + "/><br/>";
  }
  return inputs;
}


$("button").on("click",function($e){
  var specIndex = $($e.target).data('sample');
  var specData = samples[specIndex-1];

  $("#spec").html("Sample spec "+(specIndex)+" looks like: <br>"+JSON.stringify(specData));

  formBuilder(specData, $("#result"));
});
```

The last item in an array does not get a comma appended to it. Always ensure to end a line of code with a semi-colon as well. Those are the changes I made to your code, now it runs, as I assume, correctly unless you have any other issues?

Comment: The issue was not with the semi-colon, I had not attached the external JavaScript or CSS files (updated CodePen codepen.io/anon/pen/YXpBzE). The code runs but what I am trying to accomplish is inserting an HTML form in the output section of the page while using the parameters from the JavaScript without having to enter them manually in each input. @ctwheels –

Comment: @NOSDUH I'm not sure if the changes I made helped, but it basically takes parameters you set in the params section and creates inputs out of them. Let me know if you need any further questions or concerns. Hopefully this is what you're looking for

Comment: Change my code to accommodate for labels using an if statement to determine if the key sent with the each listener function is "label" and then proceed accordingly

Comment: Can you give me a short example for clarification? Thanks @ctwheels

Comment: `if(key == "label"){//do something}`